# Bootstrap 3 Accordion Effect on Table is very slow

Tags: html, css, jsp, twitter-bootstrap

I have a table which has 56 columns. We did not want any horizontal scrolling, so we decided to try an accordion effect, where the user clicks on a row (shows 7 columns by default) and it expands downwards displaying the rest of the data. When expanded, it is a total of 15 rows.

Now, when I have any more than ~5 initial rows (before expansion) displayed, it becomes veeeeery slow to perform the accordion. My guess is, because it has to re-position the table whenever this happens, the performance drastically drops with more rows displayed.

Nothing else on this webpage performs poorly. I have `.table-hover` applied and that never causes any sort of lag.

I am currently populating the table with just placeholder data via JSP, so I'm sure once I'm actually querying the database performance will drop again.

```
<table class="table table-hover table-condensed">
    <thead>
        <th></th><th nowrap>Column</th><th nowrap>Column</th>
        <th nowrap>Column</th><th nowrap>Column</th><th nowrap>Column</th>
        <th nowrap>Column</th><th nowrap>Column</th>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <%
            for(int i = 0; i < 25; i++) {%>
                <tr data-toggle="collapse" data-target="<%out.print(".record" + i);%>" class="clickable">
                    <td>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <div class="btn-group">
                                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove-sign"></span></button>
                                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span></button>
                                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span></button>
                                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus-sign"></span></button>
                             <div>
                         </div>
                    </td>
                    <td>Table Cell</td><td>Table Cell</td><td>Table Cell</td><td>Table Cell</td><td>Table Cell</td><td>Table Cell</td><td>Table Cell</td>
                </tr>
                <%
                    for(int j = 0; j < 7; J++)
                    {%>
                        <tr>
                                <th class="hiddenRow">
                                    <div class="collapse <%out.print("record" + i);%>"></div>
                                </th>
                                <th class="hiddenRow">
                                    <div class="collapse <%out.print("record" + i);%>">Hidden Column</div>
                                </th>
                                <th class="hiddenRow">
                                    <div class="collapse <%out.print("record" + i);%>">Hidden Column</div>
                                </th>
                                <th class="hiddenRow">
                                    <div class="collapse <%out.print("record" + i);%>">Hidden Column</div>
                                </th>
                                <th class="hiddenRow">
                                    <div class="collapse <%out.print("record" + i);%>">Hidden Column</div>
                                </th>
                                <th class="hiddenRow">
                                    <div class="collapse <%out.print("record" + i);%>">Hidden Column</div>
                                </th>
                                <th class="hiddenRow">
                                    <div class="collapse <%out.print("record" + i);%>">Hidden Column</div>
                                </th>
                                <th class="hiddenRow">
                                    <div class="collapse <%out.print("record" + i);%>">Hidden Column</div>
                                </th>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td class="hiddenRow">
                                    <div class="collapse <%out.print("record" + i);%>"></div>
                                </td>
                                <td class="hiddenRow">
                                    <div class="collapse <%out.print("record" + i);%>">Hidden Cell</div>
                                </td>
                                <td class="hiddenRow">
                                    <div class="collapse <%out.print("record" + i);%>">Hidden Cell</div>
                                </td>
                                <td class="hiddenRow">
                                    <div class="collapse <%out.print("record" + i);%>">Hidden Cell</div>
                                </td>
                                <td class="hiddenRow">
                                    <div class="collapse <%out.print("record" + i);%>">Hidden Cell</div>
                                </td>
                                <td class="hiddenRow">
                                    <div class="collapse <%out.print("record" + i);%>">Hidden Cell</div>
                                </td>
                                <td class="hiddenRow">
                                    <div class="collapse <%out.print("record" + i);%>">Hidden Cell</div>
                                </td>
                                <td class="hiddenRow">
                                    <div class="collapse <%out.print("record" + i);%>">Hidden Cell</div>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                      <%}
                   }
                 %>
            </tbody>
       </table>
```

Any assistance on possibly speeding this up would be great. I don't know if it's possible to, instead of pushing everything down, the accordion effect just kind of overlays over whatever is underneath? If that makes any sense.

**EDIT: CSS**
Besides Bootstrap, I don't have much extra CSS currently applied, but here it is.

```
<style type="text/css">
    td {
        white-space:nowrap;
    }

    body {
        padding-top: 50px; 
    }

    .hiddenRow {
        padding: 0 !important;
    }

    table .btn{
      padding: 1px 5px 1px;
      margin-right: -3px;
    }

</style>
```

Comment: Could you create a bootply (http://www.bootply.com/new) without the php, just plain html with the example data, so that we can test it there? Add as much example data as it needs to become slow on your setup.

Comment: Without the JSP, the HTML gets to be huge. Thousands of lines.

Comment: We just need the area of the `table`.

Comment: That's where all these lines come from...

Comment: Mhmm, that's a lot for a table. But it's hard to find the performance lack without a live example. After looking through your code again I saw an issue that might cause it, the `.collapse` classes shouldn't be on the `div`'s but on the `<tr>`'s.

Comment: Yup that was it! Made the change, bumped it up to 100 expandable rows, and it's still pretty quick. Not even half a second delay. Makes sense too, it's having to toggle that property a lot less now. Go ahead and make this an answer and I'll accept. You're a savior.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should give the `<tr>`'s the class `.collapse`, not the `<div>`'s.

So change your code from:

```
<tr>
    <td class="hiddenRow">
         <div class="collapse <%out.print("record" + i);%>">xxx</div>
    </td>
</tr>
```

to:

```
<tr class="collapse <%out.print("record" + i);%>">
    <td class="hiddenRow">
         <div>xxx</div>
    </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Thanks! This did. Performance increased greatly after this change.